# Update android application without starting an installation dialog

Tags: android, compilation, installation, apk, unpack

I'm currently looking for a way to update an android application without starting the installation intent.

### Please note, the device is rooted

If it's possible I would just like to start the installation automated without notifying the user(automated APK installation).
If that is not an option I would like to unpack the APK, compile it myself and write it to the app's data directory.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install /mnt/sdcard/tr.apk");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but this requires system permission and

```
android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
```